# Understanding Regularization in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to understand why regularization syntax in Keras looks the way that it does.

Roughly speaking, regularization is way to reduce overfitting by adding a penalty term to the loss function proportional to some function of the model weights.  Therefore, I would expect that regularization would be defined as part of the specification of the model's loss function.

However, in Keras the regularization is defined on a per-layer basis.  For instance, consider this regularized DNN model:

```
input = Input(name='the_input', shape=(None, input_shape))
x = Dense(units = 250, activation='tanh', name='dense_1', kernel_regularizer=l2, bias_regularizer=l2, activity_regularizer=l2)(x)
x = Dense(units = 28, name='dense_2',kernel_regularizer=l2, bias_regularizer=l2, activity_regularizer=l2)(x)
y_pred = Activation('softmax', name='softmax')(x)
mymodel= Model(inputs=input, outputs=y_pred)
mymodel.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

I would have expected that the regularization arguments in the Dense layer were not needed and I could just write the last line more like:

```
mymodel.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'], regularization='l2')
```

This is obviously wrong syntax, but I was hoping someone could elaborate for me a bit on why the regularizes are defined this way and what is actually happening when I use layer-level regularization.

The other thing I don't understand is under what circumstances would I use each or all of the three regularization options: `(kernel_regularizer, activity_regularizer, bias_regularizer)`?

Comment: Consider looking [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/04/fundamentals-deep-learning-regularization-techniques/). It may give you some initial insight.

Comment: I didn't find the link from the comment above to be helpful towards the question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's break down the components of your question:

1. Your expectation of regularisation is probably in line with a feed-forward network where yes the penalty term is applied to the weights of the overall network. But this is not necessarily the case when you have RNNs mixed with CNNs etc so Keras opts give fine grain control. Perhaps for easy setup, a regularisation at model level could be added to the API for all weights.
2. When you use layer regularisation, the base `Layer` class actually [adds](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7365a99f6e832847808c7aa28718d32fbc744b21/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L255) the regularising term to the loss which at training time penalises the corresponding layer's weights etc.
3. Now in Keras you can often apply regularisation to 3 different things as in [Dense](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense) layer. Every layer has different kernels such recurrent etc, so for the question let's look at the ones you are interested in but the same roughly applies to all layers:

   1. **kernel**: this applies to actual *weights* of the layer, in Dense it is the *W* of *Wx+b*.
   2. **bias**: this is the bias vector of the weights, so you can apply a different regulariser for it, the *b* in *Wx+b*.
   3. **activity**: is applied to the output vector, the *y* in *y = f(Wx + b)*.